# Forward slash being replaced with: %252F in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I've written an AngularJS App where changes in values in input boxes are dynamically updated into the URI which is split by forward slashes as a means to store data in the URI which can eventually be shared. Essentially the URL is the database. When someone visits the URI, values from the URI string are slotted back into the scope of the application. Example settings page:

http://whohe.co.uk/Quiz_Scorer_App.html#/!/TQS//////////////////////////////////

When putting values from the Input boxes into the URI, I use the following functions:

```
    $scope.go = function (term,pos) { /* Fires on Keyup, pushes term into the path */
        // var res = term.replace(/\//g, "%2F"); Fix to allow slash in fields
        $location.path(update(decodeURI($location.url()),pos,term), false);
    };


function update(line,index,term) {
    var arr = line.split("/");
    arr.splice(index,1,term);
    var res = arr.join("/");
    return res;
}
```

When getting values from the URL into the scope I use decodeURI e.g.:

```
$scope.TeamAN = decodeURI(arr[14]);
```

My problem is forward slashes. e.g. if I make an input of N/A this causes a major problem as the input crosses into the next field.

Ideally I would replace all forward slashes with %2F, but when I do that using:

```
term.replace(/\//g, "%2F")
```

the following is updated to the URI:

N%252FA - it's being doubly encoded.

Which when the page is refreshed, returns:

N%2FA

Rather than the N/A I was expecting.

Hope that is clear. Assistance is solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Are you really using `term.replace(///g, "%2F")` ? not `term.replace(/\//g, "%2F")`?

Comment: I am not using either at the moment. I tried the second one you mention, and it was what I pasted in to the box, but I just noticed it got changed to that.

Comment: can you show where the result of update is inserted into the URL?

Comment: If you click on the initial hyperlink and start typing in (e.g.) the League & Division input box, you'll see it updates the URI. This is from $scope.go in the controller.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include $scope.go and to fix the rendering of the RegEx.

Comment: Looking at your page, you are using angular-route.

Comment: Adding `term = term.replace(/\//g, "%2F")` apparently solves the problem... Can you please try again?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it produces the error described (the slash is put in the URI as %252F). The Fix note is a note to me that I need to fix it, rather than it being a Fix.

Comment: I know it puts %252F in the URI, but how is that really a problem?

Comment: When you reload the page, rather than returning as a forward slash, it returns as %2F (this can be tested by using the regex replace, inputting something with a forward slash and hitting F5). It is a problem, it's the whole problem.

Comment: Is the webpage still up? I can no longer access it after having changed location... If it is, can you please use the `replace()` and I'll have a look at how to correct the `/` being transformed into a `%2F`?

Comment: ok, I've done that, it's still up.

Comment: My internet provider cannot access your webpage, strange. But I used a webproxy so it's OK. Anyway, where you use all these `$scope.LeagueDivision = decodeURI(arr[3])`, you should replace them by `decodeURI(arr[3]).replace(/%2F/g,"/")` to do the inverse transformation.
But that's a bit heavy so you should do all the replacements inside a map loop: `var arr = url.split("/"); arr = arr.map(function(comp){return decodeURI(comp).replace(/%2F/g,"/")})` and then just do `$scope.LeagueDivision = arr[3]` where you need it.

Comment: Also, the file can be downloaded and edited locally if you need to test approaches (it's designed for offline use).... Thanks. I considered something similar, but it's still wrong in the URI.

Comment: OK. I'll try to see if we can get `$location` to have the URL store `%2F` instead of the `%252F` then.

Comment: Ok, I tried, but there is no way of having a `%2F` in the URL (without patching angular). Changing the `/` into a `%2F` will prevent the users from using `%2F` as a value, but I guess that's not a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78246/discussion-between-camusensei-and-will-jones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per discussed, start by changing the `/` into a `%2F`:

```
$scope.go = function (term,pos) { /* Fires on Keyup, pushes term into the path */
    var res = term.replace(/\//g, "%2F"); Fix to allow slash in fields
    $location.path(update(decodeURI($location.url()),pos,res), false);
};
```

Then, you need to decode the `%2F` when you read your URI:

## Old code

```
    // Fill the boxes with any values found in the URL
    var url = $location.url();
    var arr = url.split("/");
    $scope.LeagueDivision = decodeURI(arr[3]);
    $scope.Venue = decodeURI(arr[4]);
    $scope.Competition = decodeURI(arr[5]);
    $scope.PhaseMatch = decodeURI(arr[6]);
    $scope.Questioner = decodeURI(arr[7]);
    $scope.Scorer = decodeURI(arr[8]);
    $scope.TeamAN = decodeURI(arr[9]);
    $scope.TeamBN = decodeURI(arr[10]);
    $scope.Player = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) { $scope.Player[i] = decodeURI(arr[i+11]); }
    $scope.TeamAS = parseInt(0+decodeURI(arr[19]));
    $scope.TeamBS = parseInt(0+decodeURI(arr[20]));
    $scope.Start = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) { $scope.Start[i] = decodeURI(arr[i+21]); }
    $scope.First = parseInt(0+decodeURI(arr[29]));
    $scope.StartDateTime = decodeURI(arr[30]);
    $scope.TeamAC = parseInt(0+decodeURI(arr[31]));
    $scope.TeamBC = parseInt(0+decodeURI(arr[32]));
    if($scope.StartDateTime==''){
            d = new Date();
            var date = d.YYYYMMDDhhmmssmmm();
            $scope.StartDateTime = date.substring(0, date.length - 7);
            $location.path(update(decodeURI($location.url()),30,$scope.StartDateTime), false);
    }
    $scope.go = function (term,pos) { /* Fires on Keyup, pushes term into the path */
            term = term.replace(/\//g, "%2F"); // Fix to allow slash in fields
            var i = update(decodeURI($location.url()),pos,term);
            $location.path(i, false);
    };
    $scope.start = function () {
            $location.path(update(decodeURI($location.url()),2,'TQM'), true);
            if(!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(); }
    };
```

## New code

```
    // Fill the boxes with any values found in the URL
    var url = $location.url();
    var arr = url.split("/");
    arr = arr.map(function(comp){return decodeURI(comp).replace(/%2F/g,"/")});
    $scope.LeagueDivision = arr[3];
    $scope.Venue = arr[4];
    $scope.Competition = arr[5];
    $scope.PhaseMatch = arr[6];
    $scope.Questioner = arr[7];
    $scope.Scorer = arr[8];
    $scope.TeamAN = arr[9];
    $scope.TeamBN = arr[10];
    $scope.Player = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) { $scope.Player[i] = arr[i+11]; }
    $scope.TeamAS = parseInt(0+arr[19]);
    $scope.TeamBS = parseInt(0+arr[20]);
    $scope.Start = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) { $scope.Start[i] = arr[i+21]; }
    $scope.First = parseInt(0+arr[29]);
    $scope.StartDateTime = arr[30];
    $scope.TeamAC = parseInt(0+arr[31]);
    $scope.TeamBC = parseInt(0+arr[32]);
    if($scope.StartDateTime==''){
            d = new Date();
            var date = d.YYYYMMDDhhmmssmmm();
            $scope.StartDateTime = date.substring(0, date.length - 7);
            $location.path(update(decodeURI($location.url()),30,$scope.StartDateTime), false);
    }
    $scope.go = function (term,pos) { /* Fires on Keyup, pushes term into the path */
            term = term.replace(/\//g, "%2F"); // Fix to allow slash in fields
            var i = update(decodeURI($location.url()),pos,term);
            $location.path(i, false);
    };
    $scope.start = function () {
            $location.path(update(decodeURI($location.url()),2,'TQM'), true);
            if(!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(); }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for this solution. I have updated the files and uploaded. A lot of further annoyance from my attempts to fix this myself has been saved.